# How do I use jquery to get the height of a dynamically created child element with no Id

Tags: jquery, html, height

I have a div that dynamically get's loaded with two images always and possibly one div in between.  Neither the images or the div have id's associated with them (and I can't make them have Id's).  Inspecting them with firebug they are just shown as `<IMG>` and `<DIV>`.  I need to get the height of this child div when it exists.

I was hoping I could do something like this...

```
$("#parentDiv > DIV").height();
```

or this...

```
$("#parentDiv > DIV")[0].height();
```

Since jquery $ returns an array.  The second one gives javascript errors so I know I'm off there.  I think these should be close though.  Any ideas?

**Edit:**
Here is the html I am running against.

```
<DIV id="parentDiv" name="parentDiv">
    <IMG style="DISPLAY: block; VERTICAL-ALIGN: bottom; CURSOR: pointer" height="17" src="..." />

    <!-- this div may or may not be here -->
    <DIV style="DISPLAY: block; BACKGROUND-IMAGE: url(...); WIDTH: 16px; CURSOR: pointer; BACKGROUND-REPEAT: repeat-y; POSITION: relative; HEIGHT: 144px; outline: none">
        <DIV style="LEFT: 0px; OVERFLOW: hidden; WIDTH: 16px; POSITION: absolute; TOP: 128px; HEIGHT: 8px">
             <IMG style="LEFT: 0px; POSITION: absolute; TOP: 0px" height="8" src="..." />
        </DIV>
    </DIV>

    <IMG style="DISPLAY: block; VERTICAL-ALIGN: bottom; CURSOR: pointer" height="17" src="..." />
</DIV>
```

Comment: Please explain a lil more clearly? Does 'possibly one DIV in between' mean that possible DIV contains the IMGS or that possible DIV is between the IMGs? If the inner DIV does NOT exist, do you want ZERO for the resultant height ?

Comment: the div is in between the two images, I forgot to put the second image up there, I'll edit that.  If the div isn't there, null or 0 would both be fine.  I can't get the heights of the images in this manner either if that offers any insight.

Answer (score 6):

to get an indexed jQuery element, use the `eq()` function:

```
$("#parentDiv > DIV").eq(0).height();
```

or

```
$($("#parentDiv > DIV")[0]).height();
```

or

```
$("#parentDiv > DIV:eq(0)").height();
```

Comment: Thanks $($("#parentDiv > DIV")[0]).height(); is about the closest I've gotten.  It's returning an unexpected result though (664, it shouldn't be that large).  I'll have to play with it.

Comment: the problem could also be that you're using absolute positioning for the image, try setting it to something else and see if your height is saner

Comment: I think you may be right.  However, that code is auto generated.  I can move the div surround that code up there around which changes things, but I can't change any of the code I posted.

Answer (score 2):

Just to add to all the other ways of doing it:

```
$("#parentDiv > div:first").height();
```

Answer (score 1):

Your first one will work, as long as your selector is okay. Try the following and see what you get:

```
$("#parentDiv > DIV").css("background", "pink");
```

If you don't get a pink background where you'd expect, fix your selector, and it'll work with the height-statement as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$($("#parentDiv > div")[0]).height();
```

That should do the trick